# Solving error messages given by PHPdoc

Tags: php, phpdoc, documentation

**How can you solve the following error messages given by PHPdoc?**

I run *madedoc.sh* by the following command

**Command**

```
sudo ./makedoc.sh
```

I get

**Error messages**

```
PHP Version 5.2.6-3ubuntu4.2
phpDocumentor version 1.4.2

Parsing configuration file phpDocumentor.ini...
   (found in /usr/share/php/data/PhpDocumentor/)...

done
Maximum memory usage set at 256M after considering php.ini...
using tokenizer Parser

        ERROR: Converter PDFSmartyConverter specified by --output command-line option is not a class

        ERROR: No Converters have been specified by --output command-line option

        ERROR: No Converters have been specified by --output command-line option
```

**Example of comments what I am trying to generate**

```
/** Create HTML for tags
 * @param string @tags
 */
function create_tags_at_question ( $tags ) {
    echo ("<label for='tags'>Tags</label>"
        . "<input name='question[tags]' type='text' cols='92' class='tags' id='required'"
        . " value='" . $tags . "' />"
    );
}
```

**My makedoc.sh for PHPdoc**

```
#!/bin/bash
#/**
#  * title of generated documentation, default is 'Generated Documentation'
#  *
#  * @var               string TITLE
#  */
TITLE="komponentit"

#/**
#  * name to use for the default package. If not specified, uses 'default'
#  *
#  * @var               string PACKAGES
#  */
PACKAGES="default"

#/**
#  * name of a directory(s) to parse directory1,directory2
#  * $PWD is the directory where makedoc.sh
#  *
#  * @var               string PATH_PROJECT
#  */
PATH_PROJECT=$PWD:$PWD/handlers/:$PWD/handlers/searches/

#/**
#  * path of PHPDoc executable
#  *
#  * @var               string PATH_PHPDOC
#  */
PATH_PHPDOC=/usr/bin/phpdoc

#/**
#  * where documentation will be put
#  *
#  * @var               string PATH_DOCS
#  */
PATH_DOCS=$PWD/docs/

#/**
#  * what outputformat to use (html/pdf)
#  *
#  * @var               string OUTPUTFORMAT
#  */
OUTPUTFORMAT=pdf

#/**
#  * converter to be used
#  *
#  * @var               string CONVERTER
#  */
CONVERTER=Smarty

#/**
#  * template to use
#  *
#  * @var               string TEMPLATE
#  */
TEMPLATE=default

#/**
#  * parse elements marked as private
#  *
#  * @var               bool (on/off)           PRIVATE
#  */
PRIVATE=off

# make documentation
"$PATH_PHPDOC" -d "$PATH_PROJECT" -t "$PATH_DOCS" -ti "$TITLE" -dn $PACKAGES \
-o $OUTPUTFORMAT:$CONVERTER:$TEMPLATE -pp $PRIVATE
```

Comment: I replaced PHPdoc with Doxygen so the problem solved at least in the short run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bear with me ... I don't know PHPdoc, so I'm guessing a little here, until the cavalry arrives.

Something about

```
"$PATH_PHPDOC" -d "$PATH_PROJECT" -t "$PATH_DOCS" -ti "$TITLE" -dn $PACKAGES \
-o $OUTPUTFORMAT:$CONVERTER:$TEMPLATE -pp $PRIVATE
```

makes tokenizer Parser unhappy. Something in the syntax is not right.

All three errors relate to this line of makedoc.sh

- --output is probably the long form of the -o you used in makedoc.sh
- PdfSmartConverter in the first error seems to be made of several of the variables in makedoc.sh run together. Do you need spaces or some other delimiter?
- do you need more ""
- is 'pdf' enough of an outputformat specifier

As I said, I'm just guessing - but maybe it'll give you some ideas.

Now ... where is that cavalry?

Comment: The file is based on the official template file in the installer of PHPdoc. Your code is exactly the same in the installer. I did not change it. - **What do you mean by delimeter in this case?** - I apparently do not need more the character ".  - PDF is allowed to be the outputformat according to the file.

Comment: I was thinking of the : between $OUTPUTFORMAT and $CONVERTER and $TEMPLATE. Oh well, I was just guessing, as I said, and I hoped that something in my answer would cause you to say 'Aha!' But you know PHPdoc better than I ever will. I hope someone comes up with the right answer soon.